# Please suggest how to create a section in Android list

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have got a set of items whose name starts from A to Z. I wanted to add a separator for each section of letters i.e. A, B, C... Z etc...

I will be having a model object which contains not only letters but also some other data like image path, and other details.

I found a way to add separator [here](http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/). Is it good to create a Dummy model object for every section like showed above and insert to the arraylist and start using. Or can you suggest me some other idea please.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Amazing ListView Project](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)

In this you can choose the layout for the header of each section

Answer (score 0):

These are some Link for the following:

http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.in/2010/11/android-listview-header-two-or-more-in.html

http://twistbyte.com/tutorial/android-listview-with-fast-scroll-and-section-index

http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/

Comment: Bartinger code i am using, can you please tell me my above logic seems fine and optimized?

Answer (score 0):

The [GreendDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) library by [Cyril Mottier](https://github.com/cyrilmottier) contains an alphabetical section list if you are open to using external libs.

There is also the [Alphabetically project](https://github.com/rvalusa/AlphaBetically) by [|R|akesh V](https://github.com/rvalusa) which shows how such a list can be implemented.